# Crazyflie via swd st-link

Tags: stm32, crazyflie

I try to flash crazyflie quadrocopter via swd. It is stm32f103 microcontroller on copter used.
All goes as expected, but after ordinary burning chip stop to worked. Now i get followed output from st-link utility:

```
/opt/tools/stlink/st-flash --reset write ./output/mdr.bin 0x8000000
2014-12-27T12:53:47 INFO src/stlink-common.c: Loading device parameters....
2014-12-27T12:53:47 WARN src/stlink-common.c: unknown chip id! 0xe0042000
Press return ...
```

Google give me: 
https://github.com/texane/stlink/issues/107

Connect under reset and using bootloader don't give me success result both.
After power on I get this voltages:

```
SWDIO =  1.36V 
SWCLK = 1.36V,
NRST = 2.7V.
```

Same voltage on SWDIO and SWCLK I have if I set NRST pin to GND.
Is any idea what can help me?

Comment: You might want to ask the question in the official development forum here: https://forum.bitcraze.io/viewforum.php?f=6

Answer (score 0):

Clone and build from official source:

https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink

Steps:

1. **Make:** Inside the `stlink` folder:

   ```
   cmake .
   make
   ```
2. **Copy the `stlink/bin` files to:**

   ```
   sudo cp st-* /usr/local/bin
   ```
3. **Update the `udev` rules:**

   ```
   sudo cp stlink/config/udev/rules.d/49-stlinkv* /etc/udev/rules.d/
   ```